# Cross compiling hostapd getting fatal error: openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, hostapd

I am running ubuntu on system & cross-compiling (for arm arch.) hostapd. Hostapd compilation terminates with `fatal error: openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory` error.

`bn.h` file is already present at `/usr/include/openssl/bn.h`.
I tried `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` but didn't work.

can someone please point me if i am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use headers and libraries for target platform (arm). So you have to cross-compile OpenSSL first or use files installed on the target device (RPi?).

Use -I and -L parameters to point compiler (gcc?) to the right resources.

But there are no candies in the end. bn.h can be still missing, because of the compile-time settings of the OpenSSL. 
Hostapd is full of ifdefs, but there should be more of them because more headers can be missing - ie. des.h - DES is considered weak nowadays.